# Override newdocset.aspx save button to save document to a different folder based on input field

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

My goal is to manage to save a new document set in a different folder based on certain input fields.One way i thought it could be done is by somehow adding additional metadata/options or overriding the save button's `onclick="...WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions()..."` with JavaScript.